# DataBinding between Entity Framework and WinForms DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, datagrid, infragistics

I'm trying to bind an Infragistics UltraWinGrid to my Entities:

One of my models:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext class:

```
public class AppContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

An implementation for a Generic Repository

```
public class StudentRepository : Repository<Student>
{
    public StudentRepository(AppContext context) : base(context) { }      

    public IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudents()
    {
        return context.Students.Include("Course").ToList();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And a Data Access Layer:

```
public class DAL : IUnitOfWork
{
    private AppContext dbContext;
    private StudentRepository student;       

    public DAL()
    {
        dbContext = new AppContext();
    }

    // the following is probably ugly
    public AppContext getContext()
    {
        return this.dbContext;
    }

    public StudentRepository Students
    {
        get
        {
            if (students== null)
                students= new StudentRepository(dbContext);
            return students;
        }
    }        

    public int Save()
    {
        return dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (students != null)
            students.Dispose();

        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Up to now, I always used to use a `dal.Students.GetAllStudents().toList()` as a datasource, but that obviously only works for grids for reading purposes only. Now I would like to use the Update, Insert and Delete features of the grid, but I cannot figure out how.

The only way I found in the internet, is to access the Students `DbSet` inside the context:

`grid.DataSource = dal.getContext().Students.Local.ToBindingList();`

Is this really supposed to be done like that? It seems rather ugly this way.

Answer (score 1):

This is way that msdn site's sample use it: [Databinding with WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj682076)